# Android use library built with Java 10

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I want to use a maven generated artifact from another project. However, it is generated using java 10. pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>dtos</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>10</source>
                <target>10</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In the gradle.properties I add the dependency from local maven repository:

```
repositories {
    // ...
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.example:dtos:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

During compilation I get an error:

> org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
>   Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
>   ...
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

When I use Java 1.8 when compiling the maven project, the Android project works fine. How can I handle such problem?

Comment: Try change target to 8

Comment: Android doesn't know any version of Java higher than 8 so either build directly as you've posted or add to your local maven a version built with Java 8 so that you can import it.

Comment: @n3dx not possible, getting: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project dtos: Fatal error compiling: source release 10 requires target release 1.10

Ok, since Android doesn't support Java 10, I will just use 1.8 version to build it. This artifact doesn't need java > 8 enhancements.

Comment: yeah try that and let us know :)